# Matplotlib on OS without GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-server

Though the question may seem strange, sometimes it really can be useful. For example, I have to build a histogram using `plt.hist`, but I am not going to plot it, only to send the heights of the bars to the front-end side for actual plotting, and since the back-end side is run on an Ubuntu Server instance, I cannot install `matplotlib` via `pip`. Is it possible in general? Are there any other options in my particular case?

Comment: Who do you mean you "cannot install matplotlib via pip" on Ubuntu Server?

Comment: It seems pretty useless to use a plotting function like `hist` to calculate some values from the data. Just calculate the histogram and send it to the receipient without using matplotlib at all.

Comment: You can use X forwarding to run a GUI program on any compatible remote server, but that's nothing to do with python or matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the histogram values, then just calculate them directly using something like [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is the best solution for my problem